# python: How to modify dictonaries in a DataFrame?

Tags: python, dictionary, dataframe

How can I modify a list value inside dataframes? I am trying to adjust data received by JSON and the DataFrame is as below:
The dataframe has 'multiple dictionary' in one list.

```
   Dataframe df:
        id    options
    0    0     [{'a':1 ,'b':2, 'c':3, 'd':4},{'a':5 ,'b':6, 'c':7, 'd':8}]
    1    1     [{'a':9 ,'b':10, 'c':11, 'd':12},{'a':13 ,'b':14, 'c':15, 'd':16}] 
    2    2     [{'a':9 ,'b':10, 'c':11, 'd':12},{'a':17 ,'b':18, 'c':19, 'd':20}]
```

If I want to use only 'a' and 'c' key / values in options how can I modify datafames? The expected result would be

```
       Dataframe df:
        id    options
    0    0     [{'a':1 ,'c':3},{'a':5 ,'c':7}]
    1    1     [{'a':9, 'c':11},{'a':13,'c':15}] 
    2    2     [{'a':9 ,'c':11},{'a':17,c':19}]
```

I tried filtering but I could not assign the value to the dataframe

```
for x in totaldf['options']:
    for y in x:
        y = {a: y[a], 'c': y['c']} ...?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using nested listed comprehension:

```
df['options'] = [[{'a': y['a'], 'c': y['b']} for y in x] for x in df['options']]
```

If you wanted to use a for loop it would be something like:

```
new_options = []
for x in df['options']:
    row = []
    for y in x:
        row.append({a: y[a], 'c': y['c']})
    new_options.append(row)

df['options'] = new_options
```

Comment: thank you for both answers! I tested both cases. I will keep in mind the way to handle data.

Answer (score 1):

```
# An alternative vectorized solution.
df.options = df.options.apply(lambda x: [{k:v for k,v in e.items() if k in['a','c']} for e in x])

Out[398]: 
   id                                  options
0   0     [{'a': 1, 'c': 3}, {'a': 5, 'c': 7}]
1   1  [{'a': 9, 'c': 11}, {'a': 13, 'c': 15}]
2   2  [{'a': 9, 'c': 11}, {'a': 17, 'c': 19}]
```